# I am trying to write command output to a file. It's not in a readable format

Tags: java

I am trying to ouput command prompt to a file and read it in Java. Then I get `ÿþS[]e[]r[]i[]a[]l` when I try opening it with NotePad++, I see it Serial. Can you help with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. It's easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a matter of different character encodings, most likely that the file you are reading uses the UTF-16 encoding in which two bytes are used for every character. By specifying which encoding to use when reading the file with Java you should be able to overcome the problem.

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-16"));
```

Note that Notepad++ probably guessed by the contents of the file which encoding to use. You can see which encoding Notepad++ is using to read the file in the Encoding menu (and you can change this by switching to another "Encode in XXX" to see the result without changing the file).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like encoding issue mismatch, read the file (in Java) as `UTF-8`. For example:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```